# JavaScript activate on page load

Tags: javascript

I have a navigation menu within a page on my site, which has JavaScript applied to it to highlight the currently selected link.

The problem is I have the same menu on my homepage and when I click a link on the homepage, it goes to the intended section, but it doesn't initially highlight the corresponding link.

For example, on the home page, there is a nav menu with links `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. Now on the "writing" page within the site, there is also the same nav links `[1, 2, 3, etc.]`. The links on the "writing" page have javascript applied, so when a link is clicked it will highlight the selected link. But when I click link 1 from the homepage it will go to the link 1 on the "writing" page but the link wouldn't be highlighted. I would have to click another link and then go back to it to highlight it.

Here is the coding used for the nav menu within the "writing" page:

```
<div id="article-nav-container">
    
        <ul id="article-nav-pg">
            <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name1#articles-top">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name2#articles-top">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name3#articles-top">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name4#articles-top">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name5#articles-top">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name6#articles-top">6</a></li>
        </ul>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
            var loc = window.location.href; // The URL of the page we're looking at
            $('#article-nav-pg a').each(function() {
                if (loc.indexOf(this.href) !== -1) { // If the URL contains the href of the anchor
                        $(this).addClass('selected'); // Mark it as selected
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        
    </div><!-- end articles nav -->
```

The coding for the homepage nav (no JavaScript) is:

```
<ul id="article-nav">
        <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name1">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name3">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name4">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name5">5</a></li>
        <li><a href="articles.php?article=article_name6">6</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I would appreciate any help on how to link the JavaScript effect to the homepage nav menu so that when a link is clicked the corresponding page will load with the link selected. Using the existing JavaScript or any other technique. Hope this wasn't too confusing.

Here is the link to the site: [here](http://www.skyviewmarketing.net/clients/Cheryl/index.php)

Thanks,

gdinari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links on the homepage look like this: `articles.php?article=article_name4`.

The links off the homepage look like this:`articles.php?article=article_name4#articles-top`

When you click on the first link, it checks to see if that latter URL is a substring of the former URL. It isn't, so nothing is selected.

Is #articles-top actually necessary at all?

Comment: (If it is necessary, rather than use this.href directly, you would want to strip off the fragment - use indexOf to find the location of the #, and then take the substring before that.)

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. I needed to add the anchor tag, so users won't have to scroll down the page for the articles. I just added the anchors to the homepage and it worked! 

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In this line, `this` is not resolved to anchor,

```
if (loc.indexOf(this.href) !== -1) {
    // If the URL contains the href of the anchor
}
```

The following works,

```
if (loc.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) !== -1) {
     // If the URL contains the href of the anchor
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your input. I handle a simple mismatching error. When I made the links identical the javascript effect was applied the way it was intended to.

Thanks!